# Hydra config for cascade processing

Tags: fb-hydra

I am new to python and hydra and i am using hydra `multirun` for a cascade image processing.

Trying to use hydra-config as something like preset.

Considering an application using cascade functions which all of them read parameters from hydra `cfg`

`functionA` output is an input for `functionB` and `FunctionB` output is an input for `functionC` and `functionC` output is the desired Result.
But with every `run` All the process start from `functionA`

Can i do this: at end of first run, execute functionC with defined configs and then functionB with defined config? such recursive way?

i see everything works fine with current mode and at the other hand i know that i have to manage recursive computing by code but there is anyway in splitting code and then connect with hydra to do this?

it is time and energy consuming while running the app from start.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want to launch a DAG.
this is something Hydra does not cover, but you can look at other libraries like Ray or Airflow.

In principle, you can use Hydra's multirun to launch first job, which in turn will launch the dag, probably based on Hydra composed config.

One thing that might be useful is the instantiate API, which can allow you to construct a dag definition powered by the configuration.
In particular, Hydra 1.1 instantiate is recursive. Take a look at the [docs](https://hydra.cc/docs/advanced/instantiate_objects/overview) for it.

Comment: Great guide. 